# New Contributor indicator showing on user account after old question has been closed

Tags: discussion, new-contributor-indicator

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53741679/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-code-from-automatically-creating-a-close-file), which states the user is a new contributor:

[image]

The comment on the question, points to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53644088/vscode-auto-create-a-file) by the same user, which doesn't have the new contributor indicator:

[image]

According to the [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator?cb=1) post:

> Folks will see an indicator when they go to interact with new contributors (**visible for a week following their first post**) letting them know that the person is new. A handy link to our Code of Conduct will be in the notification for reference.

<sup>*emphasis mine*</sup>

The second question was asked on December 6<sup>th</sup> at 03:14, over a week ago (granted by only a few hours), meaning the new contributor indicator should no longer be shown for that user. Originally I thought it may be a caching problem, but if that was the case, I'd expect the new contributor to be showing on both of the user's posts, not just the newer one.

The first question was posted December 12<sup>th</sup> 11:06 (i.e. within the past week), so it appears as though the new contributor indicator gets reset if their first post is closed.

Comment: Even if it's inconsistent, it could still be cache.

Comment: @yivi [Should I blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Comment: I don't see why not. I would wait a bit before blowing the bug horn. As far as I know, post status isn't taken into account to display the banner. E.g. deleted posts count.

Comment: @yivi fair enough, wasn't aware that deleted posts count. I've changed to discussion instead of bug for now. Learning about deleted posts suggest that it probably will be a caching issue though.

Comment: "so it appears as though the new contributor indicator gets reset if their first post is closed". I ask myself, would that actually be a feature? I mean a *new contributor* of what exactly? Any content, or good content?

Comment: Deleted posts do *not* count. If a new user makes a post that gets deleted, and then a few years later makes another one, the indicator will show up on the new one. (@yivi)

Comment: Thanks @gparyani. I was pretty sure they weren't. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [What are the exact criteria for the "new contributor" indicator to be shown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314472/what-are-the-exact-criteria-for-the-new-contributor-indicator-to-be-shown):

> **tl;dr** We put the indicator on all the posts you make within your first week of posting. The indicator stays on each post for a week. Deleted posts aren't considered when determining if it's your first week.

The user made their first post on December 6, and as it was their first post it got the indicator. The indicator expired today.

The user then made their second post on December 12, and as it was within their first week of posting, it also got the indicator. That indicator is scheduled to expire on December 19.

Closing the first question had nothing to do with the fact that the second one also got the indicator. That one was posted in the user's first week of posting, and the indicator on each post expires once the post is seven days old.

Comment: So it *is* by design that it's this way, however it seems a little odd... If there are multiple posts in the first week, then they're all going to have the indicator showing at different times, which is slightly confusing if you go from one post to another. Would make more sense to me if they were all to expire at the same time (whether that's after 7 days from the first, or 7 days from the last doesn't really matter).

Comment: @crazyloonybin You should file a feature request over on [meta.se].